# Sample Spark Evaluator code for Streamsets

Tags: apache-spark, streamsets

I am trying to write a spark evaluator in Streamsets. I have to deal with complex SQL queries and hence would want to use data frames or datasets here. But the sample code which Streamsets provides deals with JavaRDD only. Can I have an insight on dataframe to get some headstart here ?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost certainly better off looking at using [StreamSets Transformer](https://streamsets.com/products/transformer/). Transformer has a much deeper Spark integration and will allow you to work with native Spark structures.